# Run Python Debugger "Standalone" Against Specific Django Module?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to run the Python debugger against a specific module in a Django application without running the Django webserver and then executing pdb from within a view or model?  I have a MailManager class inside a models.py file that contains some methods for sending emails.  I'd like to debug one of these methods without having to run the Django server and then GET/POST the view that would call that method.  I tried doing 'pdb myapp/models.py" and it seems to execute the very first command in my model file (which happens to be 'import logging'), but if I do 'dir(MailManager)', pdb tells me it's not defined.  Is it possible to debug methods in this model class "standalone" in the way I'm describing?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug any Python module with `python -m pdb module.py`. It will show you the first line and then you can press `n` to step line by line through the program.

To execute a Python statement, use the `p` or `pp` commands, like this: `p dir(MailManager)`. MailManager has to be defined, meaning the line where it's defined must have been executed.

You should check the documentation for PDB for more tips. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

You might want to look at Django's testing tools,
 which include a test client that fakes the server for you.
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/